# ionic 6 websocket client cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, websocket, client, ionic-native

I'm using ionic 6 (with Angular). Is there a websocket client plugin?
I want to communicate with a websocket server written in c# but I can't find any plugins to use ionic as websocket client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a dedicated ionic plugin if you just want to subscribe to a websocket. Existing angular websocket libraries should work.

I personally prefer using socket-io, which works perfectly fine: https://socket.io/

Comment: thanks, do you have an example for socket.io and angular? My url starts with "ws"

Comment: The documentation describes it very well, but here you can find a specific angular tutorial (section: Creating a socket client service). It's pretty simple to integrate: https://deepinder.me/creating-a-real-time-app-with-angular-8-and-socket-io-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the same websocket pattern on backend as the frontend. The [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/) doesn't communicate with others `websockets`, so it means you need to check first which `WS` actually you are using on backend to keep using the same on the mobile App.
[image]